# Perl read file with perl unicode representation

Tags: perl, string, unicode

I try to read a a.txt file, which is in perl's unicode representation.
\x{7ec8}

I used the following perl code test.txt to read.

```
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";  
while ( <> ) {  
  chomp;  
  print "$s_\n";  
}  
my $input = "\x{7ec8}";  
print "$input\n";
```

I run the cat a.txt |perl test.pl, and the output is

```
\x{7ec8}  
终
```

This means that the perl code can't recognize the unicode representation from a.txt, but can recognize inside the code.

Comment: Can you post code that compiles? I assume you mean `print "$_\n"` in your loop.

Comment: The question is a superset of the basic problem of decoding PERLQQ encoded data, i.e. turning the string `'\x{7ec8}'` (note the single quotes!) into `终`.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to put `STDIN` in utf8-mode:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

binmode STDIN, ":utf8";  
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";  
while ( <> ) {  
  chomp;  
  say;
}  
my $input = "\x{7ec8}";  
print "$input\n";
```

outputs:

```
终
终
```

Another option is to simply

```
use open qw(:utf8 :std);
```

which opens all file handles, and STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR, in utf8-mode.  See [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use open qw(:utf8 :std);

while ( <> ) {  
  chomp;  
  say;
}  
my $input = "\x{7ec8}";  
print "$input\n";
```

Comment: Note that `<>` reads from `STDIN` only if there are no files on command-line. If they are, nothing sets them to `utf8`. Maybe `use open ':utf8'` would be better solution for the example.

Comment: @bvr: Good point.  The stated use case, though, is `cat a.txt |perl test.pl`, for which this works fine.

Comment: @user620201: well, get 5.010 then.  ;-)  If you're writing Perl in 2011, you really should use 5.10.1 or better.  But if you don't, change `say;` to `print "$_\n";` and the code will work just fine.

Comment: I downloaded 5.10.1, and it still doesn't work. output \x{7ec8}  
终